# Store oAuth 2.0 Token in Cookies - Good Idea?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, cookies, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0

Just a quick background,

- I have built an API which authenticates user via oAuth 2.0 and returns token
- I have built the chrome extension which allows user to enter login details and send request to API for authentication

**Questions:**

> When user ticks "`Remember Me`", how do I keep the user logged in to
>   my extension, Do I store the token in Cookies?
>
> What if a user changes the password on some other device, I need to
>   re-authenticate right? but if I am getting token from cookies and then
>   those tokens are still valid on my server as I am using ASP.NET
>   Identity in my API which keeps the token valid for 14 days.

I will be grateful to know the answers to these questions.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an extension, it's best to use [`chrome.identity` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity) to securely store the tokens.

Changing a password is something that needs to be taken care of on the server side; previously-issued tokens should be invalidated as needed (and subsequent auth failure in the client should trigger interactive re-authentication).